# Missing azure mobile services support in visual studio express 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-express

I´m currently trying to set up an azure mobile service .net backend for an app. I´m using visual studio express 2013 for Windows / for Web. I installed all available updates and the recent azure sdk (2.4).

My problem now is that there is no "Azure Mobile Service" project template and mobile services is even not displayed beneath the azure entry in the server explorer.

[image: Got this from the web while I only have the german vs installed]

What did I miss to install?

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I tried to set up the mobile service with visual studio express 2012 but I stuck at the same problem. Neither the mobile service template nor the option in the server explorer is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows with Update 3 from this link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43729
I then had the mobile services node in the Server Explorer. However, the project template still isn't there. 
This was with Azure SDK 2.3 already installed and also tested with Azure SDK 2.4.

The project templates ship with Visual Studio SKUs and their updates, and I believe Mobile Services is only shipping with Pro and Ultimate for now.

One option to get that starting project is to provision your mobile service in the portal making sure to select the .NET backend. Then on the quickstart page of the portal (the little cloud to the left of the dashboard tab) select the link to create a new application. You will get an option to download the starter solution for the .NET backend (for windows apps it will also download the client). That is basically the same project you would get by choosing File -> New Project in VS pro or ultimate. You can then open the solution in VS Express for Web 2013 but not VS Express for Windows.

To publish the mobile service you'll need to do the following:

1. Go back to the portal and on the Dashboard page for your mobile service click the Download Publish Profile link and save to your local machine
2. Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and choose "Publish"
3. Import the publish profile you downloaded in step #1 and finish the publish process

So if you want to use the express versions of VS 2013, make sure you have all the updates then:

- Use VS 2013 For Windows to manage your mobile service in server explorer and build your windows clients
- Use VS 2013 For Web to build your Azure Mobile Service back end project, run locally, and publish using the publish profile.

Comment: Thank you, that works like a charm. I´m a little confused that mobile services are supported in the windows version of VS but not in Web (where all other azure features are), but... hey... for a free version this is absolutly okay.

Comment: @christoph I think the support is in the Windows version because it is intended to be used when building Windows and Windows Phone applications that consume the mobile service. Thus support for things like easily adding push notifications. The actual mobile service backend is in the Web tools because, as you stated, it's actually a web api.